# GDAL - Resize a image to a specific dimension, while maintaining ratio

Tags: gdal

I want to resize an RGBA geospatial image to a specified smaller height and width using GDAL tools while maintaining the image ratio and centering the original image content. Specifying the height and width together is important, and will required add "padding pixels".  A Python solution is ok.

Comment: I believe that gdal_translate has all the options that you need https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#gdal-translate.

Comment: Not as fas as I can see. Thanks

Comment: Did you see -projwin? As suggested in another answer gdalwarp with -te can be used for the same purpose and perhaps with less manual calculation for getting the image size / pixel size and extents right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method is to use `gdalwarp`. Below is an excerpt from a  script that I use for trimming the padded USGS DEM. To pad, you need to additionally specify `-ts <width> <height>` along with the correct `-te`. This allows you to pad off-center... See: [gdalwarp](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html) For you application, Ian's method is much much simpler!

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PIX[0]=1
PIX[1]=-1
FILE="USGS_NED_one_meter_x46y375_AL_3County_2015_IMG_2019"
STR=` gdalinfo ${FILE}.img | grep -Po 'Origin = \(\K[^)]*' `
IFS=',' read -r -a COORD <<< $STR
            COORD[0]=$( echo "${COORD[0]} + 7 * ${PIX[0]}" | bc -l )
            COORD[0]=$(printf '%.0lf\n' ${COORD[0]})
            COORD[1]=$( echo "${COORD[1]} + 7 * ${PIX[1]}" | bc -l )
            COORD[1]=$(printf '%.0lf\n' ${COORD[1]})
            COORD[2]=$( echo "${COORD[0]} + 10000" | bc )
            COORD[3]=$( echo ${COORD[1]} - 10000 | bc )

gdalwarp -overwrite \
            -te ${COORD[0]} ${COORD[3]} ${COORD[2]} ${COORD[1]} \
            ${FILE}.img \
            x46y375.img

raster2pgsql -a -F -I -s 26916 -t 100x100 x46y374.img public.ned_1m | \
            psql service=client -q > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gdal_translate` with the [`--outsize` argument](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal-translate-outsize):

> -outsize xsize[%]|0 ysize[%]|0
>
> Set the size of the output file. Outsize is in pixels and lines unless ‘%’ is attached in which case it is as a fraction of the input image size. If one of the 2 values is set to 0, its value will be determined from the other one, while maintaining the aspect ratio of the source dataset.

Comment: -projwin may be a good additional argument.

Comment: possibly, though if simply resizing is all they want then just outsize will work

Comment: Thanks. Will this work if I want to set the output size for both width and height e.g 150 x 100 when the original ratio is not 1.5

Comment: It will but your image will become distorted. You can specify either w by h or w or height and keep the aspect ration

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I want. I need the aspect ration maintained and padding to be added.

Comment: You did not mention padding in your question so please edit it. I suggest to draw a sketch. You can achieve what you want by defining projwin that is larger than your image. Extra space will be filled with nodata.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it clearer. Using Cal Abel's approach with gdalwarp -ts and -te worked for me.